Issue upgrading to Spring Boot 3.X
I am currently using spring boot parent version 3.1.12, trying to upgrade it to latest version (3.3.2), it gives following error while launching application. I am not using JDBC Client anywhere in code using JDBC Template.
Error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.JdbcClient]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.JdbcClient]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:341) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:390) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:278) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:81) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:280) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:102) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:81) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:160) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:427) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:771) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:589) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at com.rbc.rbccm.sry0.meta.ExpenseTrackingApplication.main(ExpenseTrackingApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.JdbcClient
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:121) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:291) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:331) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    ... 30 common frames omitted

Here is pom xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>meta-webapp-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0.SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>joinfaces-dependencies</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>4.3.3</version> -->
                <version>5.1.4</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>3.3.0</version> -->
                <version>4.0.2</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.0</version>
             <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Remove org.springframework.security from dependencyManagement. Remove the spring-security-core, spring-web, spring-core, spring-beans, spring-expression, spring-context, jackson-databind, snakeyaml. Add spring-boot-starter-web as a dependency. Remove the exclusions not needed. I also wonder why you need to have the assembly plugin as spring-boot-maven-plugin already creates a fat jar.

There is some issue in the dependencies of the project: you are using Spring Boot 3.3.2, which imports Spring Core 6.1.11, but in the error logs the 6.0.12 version is referenced. This may cause the issue, since JdbcClient has been introduced just since Spring Framework 6.1; even if you don't use the JdbcClient in your own code, it may be used in the autoconf initial process.
Try to check if some of the managed dependencies force a downgrade of the Spring Framework modules, in that case try to use a more updated version (e.g. the 4.1.5 for spring-cloud-services-dependencies), or pull back the parent pom version, to make all more coherent.

It is not necessary to explicitly include fundamental Spring dependencies. The required core Spring libraries are already included in Spring Boot's startup dependencies, such as spring-boot-starter-jdbc. Incorporating these libraries explicitly may result in version mismatches and classpath issues.
Please remove the following dependencies to run your solution.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

